# Mostrar una selección de productos "Agotados" en Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de encontrar una solución a la petición de un cliente, sin éxito. Lo que ella quiere es mostrar un determinado número de productos agotados en su tienda online. Aunque de forma predeterminada los ajustes de Woocommerce están configurados para "ocultar productos fuera de stock", quiere seleccionar algunos de sus productos ya agotados y mostrarlos (aunque no haya unidades, porque quiere decirles a sus clientes que esos pocos productos estarán disponibles pronto -hay un texto para esto en la ficha del producto-).

Hemos intentado con un snippet muy simple usando el hook woocommerce_product_is_visible que pensamos que funcionaría, pero hay algo que nos falta ...

Este es el código:

```
// [WooCommerce] Muestra algunos productos sin de stock aunque esté activada la opción de ocultarlos
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'keep_showing_specific_out_of_stock_product_list', 10, 2 );
function keep_showing_specific_out_of_stock_product_list( $visible, $product_ID ){

    $product_list = array( 18013, 18050 ); // Escribe dentro de los paréntesis, el listado de IDs de productos que quieras seguir mostrando separados por coma

    return in_array( $product_ID, $product_list )? true : $visible;
}
```

Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida :)

Comment: estas seguro que el snippet se ejecuta? has probado a sacar por pantalla `$visible` y  `$product_ID`  para asegurarte que llegan los valores esperados?  La lógica de la función parece correcta.

Comment: @Fly la verdad es que no funcionaba. Pero mira, al final me lo han resuelto en la versión en inglés de Stackoverflow. Y era tan sencillo como usar un shortcode... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622905/show-selected-out-of-stock-products-in-woocommerce/53623204?noredirect=1#comment94130486_53623204

Comment: Genial!! Me lo apunto.